# Can I move a RAID drive to another Sata port?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid

I currently have a `Windows Server 2008 R2` machine with `4 x 1TB` drives in software `RAID5` controlled by WS 2K8. I am planning to upgrade to `4 x 3TB` in the same software `RAID5`. Clearly 8 sata ports (9 with the OS drive) is more than most motherboards can offer. Mine included.

If I add a PCI sata card with some extra ports and set up the new drives on that, can I take the old drives out afterwards and move the new ones to the motherboard ports? Or will this mess up the RAID array? Im assuming that since its software RAID WS2K8 should be smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: I suppose I should call it an array

Comment: Software RAID in Windows shouldn't have a problem. It certainly won't mess up the array. At worst, the array doesn't appear in the host OS and the drives on the new SATA expansion card appear as foreign disks. If you already have an expansion card and a server to play with, my suggestion is to go ahead and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, Windows Server performs well with `RAID5` array movement. After moving the new array to different ports, it was automatically picked up. The only thing that was an issue is that the array needed to resynchronize.